# MSAL Azure B2C: which field do I send as bearer token to make authorized API requests?

Tags: azure, authentication, authorization, azure-ad-msal, azure-ad-b2c

I have React (full-stack Next.js) application which uses Azure B2C with MSAL for authentication. I got the `PKCE` login flow (just has Google as provider) working and I am calling `acquireTokenSilent` to acquire token to use for authorizing API calls to the back-end (back-end based on ASP.NET Core to be implemented later).

Which part of the response should be sent as `Bearer` from the Next.js application to the back-end to Authorize requests and use as user ID in the database?

How I acquire the token can be seen in the following snippet.

```
const Home: NextPage = () => {
  const { instance, accounts } = useMsal();

  useEffect(() => {
    if (!accounts.length) return;
    instance
      .acquireTokenSilent({
        scopes: [],
        account: accounts[0],
      })
      .then((token) => console.log("token:", token));
  });

  return (
    <div className={styles.container}>
      <button onClick={handleClick(instance)}>login</button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

This logs out the following response as seen in the snippet below. I have changed the strings to `"STRING"` for security to be sure as this just for demonstration purposes. The empty strings `""` mean the strings are empty from the response.

```json
{
    "authority": "STRING",
    "uniqueId": "STRING",
    "tenantId": "",
    "scopes": [],
    "account": {
        "homeAccountId": "STRING",
        "environment": "STRING",
        "tenantId": "",
        "username": "EMAIL",
        "localAccountId": "STRING",
        "name": "John Doe",
        "idTokenClaims": {
            "exp": "NUMBER",
            "nbf": "NUMBER",
            "ver": "STRING",
            "iss": "STRING",
            "sub": "STRING",
            "aud": "STRING",
            "nonce": "STRING",
            "iat": "NUMBER",
            "auth_time": "NUMBER",
            "idp_access_token": "STRING",
            "name": "STRING",
            "idp": "STRING",
            "oid": "STRING",
            "emails": [
                "STRING"
            ],
            "tfp": "STRING"
        }
    },
    "idToken": "STRING",
    "idTokenClaims": {
        "exp": "NUMBER",
        "nbf": "NUMBER",
        "ver": "STRING",
        "iss": "STRING",
        "sub": "STRING",
        "aud": "STRING",
        "nonce": "STRING",
        "iat": "NUMBER",
        "auth_time": "NUMBER",
        "idp_access_token": "STRING",
        "name": "JOHN DOE",
        "idp": "google.com",
        "oid": "STRING",
        "emails": [
            "EMAIL"
        ],
        "tfp": "STRING"
    },
    "accessToken": "",
    "fromCache": false,
    "expiresOn": null,
    "correlationId": "STRING",
    "familyId": "",
    "tokenType": "",
    "state": "",
    "cloudGraphHostName": "",
    "msGraphHost": "",
    "fromNativeBroker": false
}
```

Comment: Why is `scopes` an empty array?

Comment: @GauravMantri First of all, thank you for your response. I am still learning about azure B2C in general. I tried to make it minimal to have a sense of how to work with it. In one of the tutorials, I had to set-up a scope. I just added the scope "task.read" to the scopes array to see if it generates an accessToken but it is still an empty response. I have two applications in my B2C. Sample.WebApp and Sample.API. The task.read scope refers to the Sample.API and it has been set up in the API permisssions of Sample.WebApp (which has the user flow).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

You need to send `accessToken` as bearer. You can acquire the `accessToken` by defining scopes. It's important to remember you need the full URI. The mistake I made is defining it as `task.write` instead of full url as in the following example:

```
https://contoso.onmicrosoft.com/43o34te-befa-4445-aaaa-bbbbbbbbb/tasks.write
```